# Influxdb GroupBy time uses predefined intervals and does not start with the first timestamp

Tags: grafana, influxdb, influxql

I am using Influxdb to store some data representing requests being made to certain services. I want to calculate the number of requests done in one second in a time interval of 5 seconds (multiple requests might happen in one second). In order to achieve this I have written this query in order to obtain the amount of requests happening during 5 seconds time period
`select sum(Value) as RequestSum from Requests where group by time(5s) fill(0)`. The issue that I am facing is that instead of creating intervals starting with the first timestamp registered which in my case would look like `2020-10-16 14:09:13` it always starts with something ending in a number of seconds divisible by 5 like `2020-10-16 14:09:10`.

The same case happens when I try to group by time(6s), when the first timestamp it starts grouping by is `2020-10-16 14:09:12`.

Is there a way to force Influx to start grouping by from a certain timestamp and not one that seems predefined?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I have managed to find the solution I had to add a where clause containing the start time and the end time and also the `group by time(5s)` had to be change into `group by time(5s, starttime)` making the query look something like `select sum(Value) as RequestSum from Requests where time>=1605197046000ms and time<=1605197120000ms group by time(5s, 1605197046000ms) fill(0)`

Comment: I had the same issue, so to build on this I'll add my query.

`select sum(elapsed) FROM MyTable where time>='2023-10-20T07:00:00Z' GROUP BY time(8h, 7h)`

This allowed me to group data by 8 hour shifts, starting at 7am